# Validating password with cross language hash using bcrypt

Tags: php, node.js, express, passwords, bcrypt

I have database that store user credentials that have password hashed by Yii2 function, which is `Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password);`

Is there any proper way to validate the password using node.js? been trying this code, but keep returning `false`

```
bcrypt.compare(plainTextPassword, hashedPasswordFromYii2, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(res); // Should output true if the passwords match
});
```

as its here the source code of the hash generator from yii2 source

```
protected function generateSalt($cost = 13)
{
    $cost = (int) $cost;

    if ($cost < 4 || $cost > 31) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Cost must be between 4 and 31.');
    }

    // Get a 20-byte random string
    $rand = $this->generateRandomKey(20);

    // Form the prefix that specifies Blowfish (bcrypt) algorithm and cost parameter.
    $salt = sprintf('$2y$%02d$', $cost);

    // Append the random salt data in the required base64 format.
    $salt .= str_replace('+', '.', substr(base64_encode($rand), 0, 22));

    return $salt;
}

public function generatePasswordHash($password, $cost = null)
{
    if ($cost === null) {
        $cost = $this->passwordHashCost;
    }

    if (function_exists('password_hash')) {
        /* @noinspection PhpUndefinedConstantInspection */
        return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => $cost]);
    }

    $salt = $this->generateSalt($cost);
    $hash = crypt($password, $salt);

    // strlen() is safe since crypt() returns only ascii
    if (!is_string($hash) || strlen($hash) !== 60) {
        throw new Exception('Unknown error occurred while generating hash.');
    }

    return $hash;
}
```

EDIT

> Sorry for not mentioning it early, but the database password cannot be
> modified or re-registered with node.js hashed, the database need to be
> keep used by existing apps

please help, any suggestion would help

Comment: Reading the code, it's most likely that [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) was used, which is available in PHP since version 5.5. A simple way to avoid complicated code, to emulate what PHP does, is to let PHP do the verification of the the password.

Comment: I must again stress that it will be hard to emulate [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify) with Node.JS. For instance, you might have hashes, in your database, that were generated differently because PHP has changed the method several times. The best way is therefore to [call PHP to verify the password](https://promincproductions.com/blog/run-php-script-node-js/). The PHP scripts for this are very simple.

Comment: This could be a temporary situation. As soon as someone logs in you can store a hash using methods of Node.js, and use those in the future. As soon as enough users have a new hash you can retire the PHP method.

Answer (score 0):

Node js is an alternative to php. What you want is easier in node js. As you register a new user with a password, it is first hashed like this before storing the results:

```
userSchema.pre("save", async function(next){
if(!this.isModified('password')){
    next();
}
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
```

});

Then comparisons with the log in password made like this:

```
userSchema.methods.isPasswordMatched = async function(enteredPassword){
return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
```

};

Now all that's left is creating an instance of the user schema and comparing the passwords while logging in like this:

```
const loginUserCtrl = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
const {email, password} = req.body;
const findUser = await User.findOne({email});
if(findUser && (await findUser.isPasswordMatched(password))){
    const refreshToken = generateRefreshToken(findUser?.id);
    const updateUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(findUser.id,
        {
            refreshToken: refreshToken,
        },
        {new: true
        });

    res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, {httpOnly: true, maxAge: 72*60*60*1000});
    
    res.json({
        _id: findUser?._id,
        firstName: findUser?.firstName,
        lastName: findUser?.lastname,
        email: findUser?.email,
        mobile: findUser?.mobile,
        token: generateToken(findUser?._id),
    });
}else{
    throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
}
console.log(email, password);
```

});

Comment: So the comparison during log in is called inside the if statement.